# Passing number from HTML to JS function, becomes "undefined" in JS. Why?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is the PHP and HTML:

```
<?php $rowCountInDataTable=600; ?>
...
<button onclick="<?php echo "showNextRows($rowCountInDataTable)"; ?>"></button>;
```

Here is the JS:

```
function showNextRows(totalRowCount) {
    alert("button clicked");//check
    alert("Total row count: " . totalRowCount);//check
    console.log("Total row count: " . totalRowCount);//check
    ...
}
```

Both `alert` and `console.log` print **`undefined`**. The question is why? and what can I do to get the correct value in JS, which is `600`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike PHP, in JavaSript the concatenation operator is `+`, not `.`, as you have written.

Change dots to pluses. i.e.:

```
alert("Total row count: " + totalRowCount); //check
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take this approach and just assign your row count as a data attribute on the button then use jQuery to grab it when the button is clicked.

PHP/HTML:

```
<?php $rowCountInDataTable=600; ?>
...
<button class="row-count-button" data-row-count="<?= $rowCountInDataTable ?>"></button>
```

Javascript:

```
$('button.row-count-button').on('click', function() {
    var totalRowCount = $(this).data('row-count-button');
    alert("button clicked");//check
    alert("Total row count: " + totalRowCount);//check
    console.log("Total row count: " + totalRowCount);//check
});
```

Comment: There's still a problem with the javascript.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Well, you're using "." Instead of "+" between the strings in log and alert

Comment: Ah yes good catch I'd just copied and pasted that in from the above question, didn't notice that was incorrect as well.